# Sum values from different objects filtering by ID in mongodb

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, object, mongoose

I need to to sum the working time by employeeId. I mean, objects 3 and 5 (of the collection below) belong to the same employeeId (63fefac1ce76e418acc00ee7). What should I do to have the number of working hours?

I tried to use Mongoose aggregate, but no success so far.

**COLLECTION**

```
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("64036f7ac0829fe25c6ef435"),
    clockIn: 2023-03-04T06:28:06.433Z,
    clockOut: 2023-03-04T10:30:08.601Z,
    employeeId: ObjectId("63feed3c60a04fbc61c52f91"),
    createdAt: 2023-03-04T16:19:06.436Z,
    updatedAt: 2023-03-04T16:19:08.601Z,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("64036f8fc0829fe25c6ef43b"),
    clockIn: 2023-03-04T06:27:27.013Z,
    clockOut: 2023-03-04T15:02:28.142Z,
    employeeId: ObjectId("63feece460a04fbc61c52f89"),
    createdAt: 2023-03-04T16:19:27.014Z,
    updatedAt: 2023-03-04T16:19:28.142Z,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("64036fb0c0829fe25c6ef442"),
    clockIn: 2023-03-04T06:32:00.570Z,
    clockOut: 2023-03-04T15:01:01.676Z,
    employeeId: ObjectId("63fefac1ce76e418acc00ee7"),
    createdAt: 2023-03-04T16:20:00.571Z,
    updatedAt: 2023-03-04T16:20:01.677Z,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("64036fd3c0829fe25c6ef448"),
    clockIn: 2023-03-04T07:35:35.630Z,
    clockOut: 2023-03-04T16:49:27.038Z,
    employeeId: ObjectId("63fef8c7ce76e418acc00e98"),
    createdAt: 2023-03-04T16:20:35.631Z,
    updatedAt: 2023-03-04T16:49:27.044Z,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("64037df808650d277693f106"),
    clockIn: 2023-03-03T06:31:56.290Z,
    clockOut: 2023-03-03T15:03:58.632Z,
    employeeId: ObjectId("63fefac1ce76e418acc00ee7"),
    createdAt: 2023-03-04T17:20:56.302Z,
    updatedAt: 2023-03-04T17:20:58.633Z,
    __v: 0
  }`
```

This is my Axios get, but the result brings up the number of working hours by day and not summing days as needed.

**GET**

```
timesheetRouter.get('/timesheet/:clockIn/:clockOut/show', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const clockInOutTimesheet = await Timesheet.find().populate('employeeId', 'name employeeCode department fulltime')
    return res.status(200).json(clockInOutTimesheet)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    return res.status(500).json({message: "Error code 1001"})
  }
})
```

The result should be something like that:

```
employeeId: 63feed3c60a04fbc61c52f91 ==> 4.03 hours
employeeId: 63feece460a04fbc61c52f89 ==> 8.08 hours
employeeId: 63fefac1ce76e418acc00ee7 ==> (7.98 + 8.03) = 16.01 hours
employeeId: 63fef8c7ce76e418acc00e98 ==> 8.73 hours
```

Answer (score 0):

- need to change date to ISODate
- group by `empoyeeId` and `$sum` average in minutes
- convert to hours

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$employeeId",
      averageTime: {
        $sum: {
          $avg: {
            $dateDiff: {
              startDate: {
                $dateFromString: {
                  dateString: "$clockIn",
                },
              },
              endDate: {
                $dateFromString: {
                  dateString: "$clockOut",
                },
              },
              unit: "minute",
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      hours: {
        $round: [
          {
            $divide: ["$averageTime", 60],
          },
          2,
        ],
      },
    },
  },
]);
```

[MONGO-PLAYGROUND](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Zr06s3oVYkX)